# How do I allow users to submit issues to my public repository?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a public repository on Azure DevOps.
When I enter in incognito I can see that users can only view work items, but cannot create them.

What is the proper way to allow issue submittion? Like the "Issues" section in GitHub repositories...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,there is currently no **submit issues to my public repository** this function.
You can submit issue in this forum： https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com。

> When I enter in incognito I can see that users can only view work
>   items, but cannot create them.

For this issue ,this is a normal situation.The function is designed like this.

Comment: Seriously?? Am I going to have to move my repository to GitHub just because of that?? Any plans to support it in the close future?

Comment: Yes,you can make suggestions in this link:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21.